# Incoming Remote Desktop Connection causes my system to power cycle

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

Using Remote Desktop Connection (from a laptop), I can connect to my desktop system and reach the Log On to Windows dialog. When I enter my account info and attempt to log on, the desktop system immediately power cycles. It doesn't go through any shutdown process, so I would guess some severe system error is causing it to reboot. Has anyone seen something like this before?

EDIT:
The above behavior occurs when I'm logged into the same account. I tried logging out (on the desktop machine) before connecting and the desktop system froze instead of power cycling.

System:
Running XP Pro Version 2002 Service Pack 3
NVIDIA Quadro FX 3450/4000 SDI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems like this are sometimes caused by buggy video drivers in the remote machine. It's possible that the remote machine (desktop) blue-screens and that causes the automatic restart.

You could try updating your desktop's graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know that, for this case, there is a solution, but i would like to share my case.

I have many Virtual Machines, Im using VMware Workstation 9 in many hosts; only the VMs with Windows XP rebooted when a RDP connection was tried.

Here we are many users, and not all of us where using the same resolution, so finally i found that was the cause, the driver in the guests XP machines, I upgraded it to the latest on the guests, but no solution

So here is an alternative solution:

In XP guest VM, run gpedit.msc, then go to

Computer configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components >Terminal Services

There in the right window select "Limit maximum color depth" or something like that (im using Spanish Language) and enable this feature, I selected 15 bits.

Now, it does not matter if someone select 15, 16, 24 or 32 bits, the guest, in this case server, will connect the clients to 15 bits

Hope this helps